# Disabling KeyboardInterrupt after it has been used once

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

```
Cont = 1
while Cont == 1:
    try:
        while Cont == 1:
            counter = counter + 0.1
            counter = round(counter, 1)
            print(counter)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if counter == crashNumber:
                Cont = 0
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        Multiplier = counter
```

Here the counter will continue to count up unitl it reaches the `crashNumber`, when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, it will take the number that the `counter` is at and use it for the `Multiplier` to be used later.

However I only want to give the user the chance to press this once, then it is disabled. Is there any way that this can be done?

Comment: Do you want to prevent the exception from being thrown in the first place, or just deal with it in a different way?

Comment: I just want the user to press ctrl + c once then prevent ctrl + c from doing anything after that, I don't know the best way of going about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyboardInterrupt` exception will be thrown whether you want it or not: the solution, then, is to deal with the exception in different ways in your `except` block. My chosen implementation will use a simple boolean value that starts as `True` and is set to `False` on the first interruption:

```
import time

allow_interrupt = True
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        print ('...')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if allow_interrupt:
            print ('interrupted!')
            allow_interrupt = False
```

Let me know if this addresses your use case.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!